# Can't extend a class in Java

Tags: java, classcastexception, extends

i feel stupid ask this question, but i really dont see the problem. Compiling it gave me ClassCastExeption

This is the super class

```
package elements;
import persistence.postgres.DataSource;
import persistence.postgres.IdBroker;
import persistence.postgres.PersistenceException;
import util.Util;

public class Hotspot {
private double lat;
private double lng;
private long id;
private String username;
private String time_stamp;
private String point_of_interest;
private String comment;

public Hotspot(double lat, double lng, String username, String comment, String p_o_i) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.username = username;
    try {
        this.id = IdBroker.getId(new DataSource().getConnection());
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    time_stamp = Util.timeStamp();
    this.comment = comment;
    this.point_of_interest = p_o_i;
}

public Hotspot(double lat, double lng, String username, long id,  String time_stamp) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.username = username;
    this.id = id;
    this.time_stamp = time_stamp;
}

//Getter Setter for all variable and HashCode/Equals

}
```

And this is the subcalss

```
package persistence.postgres;

import elements.Details;
import elements.Hotspot;

public class HotspotProxy extends Hotspot {
private HotSpotDAOpostgres hsd;
private Details details;

//insert
public HotspotProxy(double lat, double lng, String username, String comment, String poi) {
    super(lat, lng, username, comment, poi);
    this.hsd = new HotSpotDAOpostgres();
}

//Retrieve
public HotspotProxy(double lat, double lng, String username, long id, String time_stamp) {
    super(lat, lng, username, id, time_stamp);
    this.hsd = new HotSpotDAOpostgres();
}

public String getPointOfInterest() {
    redifined method
}

public String getComment() {
        //redifined method
}
}
```

and this give me error

```
Hotspot h = new Hotspot(31.124, 43.123, "name", "comment", "point of interest");
HotspotProxy hp = (HotspotProxy)h;
```

Please tell me where im failing. thanks for any suggention

Comment: It's worth noting on all the answers below that it's not strictly true that you can *never* cast from super to subclass. Rather, there is no *guarantee* that the cast will succeed. Examples of common downcasts include `(Graphics2D) g` and `(AbstractDocument) e.getDocument()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Hotspot      := Animal
HotspotProxy := Dog
```

You can cast a `Dog` to an `Animal` (from special to general, or in other words from subclass to baseclass), but not the other way around (from general to special, or in other words from baseclass to subclass), because every `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Dog`.

If you had something like

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

then, the following would be allowed:

```
Dog d = (Dog) a;
```

because `a` is actually a `Dog`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast an instance of a *superclass*  to a *subclass*.

That's right that `HotspotProxy` is also an `Hotspot`, but.. **not all** `Hotspot`s are `HotspotProxy`s.

Note that this is **not  a compilation error**. It's a **run-time error**. That's because you did the cast (explicit cast!), so basically you told the compiler to *trust* you that you know what you do, but.. you don't. So the compiler will say "OK, I'll compile, he knows what he's doing", but when you run the program, you'll get a **run-time** error.

(If you remove the cast, you'll indeed get a compilation error).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to cast a Super Class object to Sub Class.

```
Hotspot h = new Hotspot(31.124, 43.123, "name", "comment", "point of interest");
HotspotProxy hp = (HotspotProxy)h;
```

You had done a type-coercion in the second statement and fooled the compiler in believing that `h` is indeed a `HotspotProxy` object . Compiler allows this because `Hotspot h` can refer to any object of its subclass. So if the previous line was `Hotspot h = new HotspotProxy()` , this cast would have succeeded .But at run time JVM finds that you have violated the trust of the compiler and `h` is an object of `Hotspot` , not `HotspotProxy` and hence it throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a object variable is in fact an instance of a subclass of whatever the variable is.  For example, you could have

```
Hotspot h = new HotspotProxy(...)
```

because a `HotspotProxy` is a `Hotspot`. In that situation the boolean `(h instanceof HotspotProxy)` would be `true`.  However in your case, the `h` variable is `Hotspot` so `(h instanceof HotspotProxy)` would be `false` and the cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if HotSpot is instance of hostspotproxy

```
if(h instanceof HotspotProxy)
HotspotProxy hp = (HotspotProxy)h;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can downcast, provided that the reference variable you are using actually points to a subclass object.
For example, let's say class Dog extends class Animal.

Then

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Animal b = new Animal();

Dog d1=(Dog)a; //this works
Dog d2=(Dog)b; //this fails at run time
```

The compiler will trust us when we cast this way: all it ensures is that the objects belong to same inheritance hierarchy. So this will compile fine. But in the second case here, as well as in yours, this throws ClassCastException be.

You can check your code before downcasting to prevent such errors:

```
if(HotSpot1 instanceof HotSpotProxy)
{
 HotSpotProxy hsp= (HotSpotProxy) HotSpot1;
}
```